# How to know which model to use for multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

So I have a data that has continuous outcome (risk score) and a mix of continuous and categorical variables (that I converted into factors), I ran multiple linear regression but I got R squared of 1, so I checked for any multicolinearity using pair.wise and I found that 2 variables have correlation of 0.99, I tried to drop one of them but I still got R squared of 1 so I had to drop both of them in addition to another third continuous variable and I ran the model again, I still get not normally distributed plots for residuals and predicted vs residual plot. I tried to run multiple nonlinear regression, using gam function from mgcv library, I varied between smooth spline and loess, but I still get not good looking plots, finally I tried to square, raise variables to the power of 2,3,4,5,6,7 didn't work. I gave up, what model should I choose to fit the data? or I don't necessirly need to see good plots to consider it a good model? My linear regression plots are here:[image] [image]

Non linear regression plots are here: [image] [image]

Comment: What do your scatterplots of the data look like before you enter them into a regression? Seems something extreme is going on with your data.

Comment: What does $R^2=1$ have to do with multicollinearity or (especially) feature correlation?

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand QQplots for 5 variables are normally distributed but 2 show deviation from normality

Comment: @Dave it may noy be relevant but it is not correct to have Rsquared of 1 right? plus the correlation btween two variables was 0.99 so very very high

Comment: But what does $R^2=1$ have to do with feature correlation?

Comment: @Dave having R squared of means it is linear equation not linear regression anymore, what do you think the problem then?

Comment: Depending on you you do the $R^2$ calculation, $R^2=1$ means that the error variance is zero. That is, the model gets every prediction perfect. There are reasons to be skeptical that such performance is reasonable and not just due to overfitting, but $R^2=1$ isn't inherently a problem, and I certainly do not see the relationship between $R^2=1$ and feature correlation.

Comment: @Dave thank you, but looking at the plots for linear regression makes me skeptical about the linear regression

Comment: @RaneemDaqqa I'm aware of what a QQ plot is. What do the scatters show on the raw data?